# C# - Skype user validation (RE)

Tags: c#, regex, skype

I saw this post in internet about the restrictions on Skype name

> A Skype username cannot be shorter than six characters or longer than
>   32. It can contain both letters and numbers, but must start with a letter; accented characters are not allowed. The only punctuation
>   marks you can use are commas, dashes, periods and underscores.

What is the regular expression that restrict these rules in C#?

Regards

Comment: You should try first and then show your effort. You should generate some input to be passed and some not to be passed

Comment: Show what you have done so far?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: > Please see Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?
 @EJoshuaS
Thank you dear for the useful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this:

`/^[A-Za-z\d\,\-\.\_]{6,32}$/`

**EDIT**: make alphabets case-insensetive

Comment: > const string SkypeRE = "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\\d\\,\\-._]{6,32}$";
This worked for me, you were just missing "must start with letter" .
Thank you dear